# Dependency injection with Orleans

Tags: dependency-injection, orleans

I'm not sure how or where to inject dependencies into a Grain. Where's the best place to do this?

If it's not possible, should I set up a container in the WorkerRole.Run method and get instances as I need them?

Comment: It seems [DI support was added to Orleans](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/669), but it's not yet in any released version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a limited support for DI in the grains. This feature is being promised to be delivered soon , but as in 1.0.9 - there is no traditional constructor injection.

So far you can use (anti-pattern) ServiceLocator using frameworks of your choice (e.g we are using Autofac and CommonServiceLocator for that) for resolving services you want to call inside your grain instance.

For the unit testing - there is a Grain constructor which can be used to construct grain instance with mocks (see [more details here](https://gitter.im/dotnet/orleans?at=55b4b51361d39fd7160673cc) )

I'd invite you to the Orleans gitter chat (as via link above) where you can see answers and discussions around some other burning questions.

Answer (score 10):

Since [orleans 1.1.0](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/releases/tag/v1.1.0) release, orleans team added "ASP.NET vNext style Dependency Injection for grains", you can see an example of this in [here](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/a64fa8953e764ac391ebd549d395ac66374b545f/src/TestGrains/SimpleDIGrain.cs)

Also to see how "ASP.NET vNext Dependency Injection" works see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx)